# fly watch on current job inside on_error?

Tags: concourse, concourse-fly

I want to get the results of the `fly watch` command for the current build on the on_error hook so I can report the details of the error into Slack.

I found a way to do this using a custom resource, however, since the job is still running during the on_error, it just loops endlessly which effectively hangs the concourse build and VM.

Is there a way to get the `fly watch` output for a pipeline?  Alternatively, is there a way to tell the `fly watch` command to just return the data is has and not continue to query for more output?